# How can I go back from vimdiff to netrw?

Tags: netrw

I list files using `vim .`, which uses `netrw`. Then I select two files using `md`, and open them in diff mode using `mf`. Now how can I go back to the list of files?
I use `:q` to exit the second file, and `:E` to list them again, but are there shorter ways? if not how can I define these composition of keys in netrw rc?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant `md` to diff, I would do `<C-w>o` to get back to one window and `:Rex` (short for `:Rexplore`) to go to the listing. (Don't use the window command, short for `:only`, if you have other windows you don't want to close!).

Comment: That is a lot keystroke, I want one key, no command. How can I map these procedure to one key?

Comment: I forgot to say thank anywas

Comment: @Ahmad I find it quite short, but if you want to make a mapping you should look at `:help :map`. Example: `nnoremap <leader>r <C-w>o:Rexplore<CR>`. Assuming your leader is backslash (the default), press backslash-r.